Unexpected error when trying to send a email via spring boot
I needed to write a service for sending emails, but no matter how many sources I looked at java mailer documentation, nothing comes out and crashes with an unexpected error:
"Mail server connection failed. Failed messages: org.eclipse.angus.mail.util .MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;\n nested exception is:\n\tjava.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect".
Please tell me, maybe I overlooked something somewhere.
Here is my service, which is embedded in another through DI using the interface, there can be no errors there:
@Service
public class EmailService implements IEmailService{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailService.class);
    private final JavaMailSender _javaMailSender;

    public EmailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender){
        _javaMailSender=javaMailSender;
    }

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}") private String sender;

    @Override
    public ServiceResponse<String> sendEmail(String recipientEmail, String subject, String message) throws Exception {
            var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<String>();
            try {

                MimeMessage messageM = _javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
                MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(messageM, true);
                mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(sender);
                mimeMessageHelper.setTo(recipientEmail);
                mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);
                mimeMessageHelper.setText(message);
                _javaMailSender.send(messageM);
                serviceResponse.data=null;
                serviceResponse.success=true;
                serviceResponse.message=String.format("Security code for %s successfully sent to your email.", subject);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                serviceResponse.data=null;
                serviceResponse.success=false;
                serviceResponse.message=ex.getMessage();
            }
            return serviceResponse;
    }

Here is my application.yml:
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    username: myemail@gmail.com
    password: **** **** **** ****
    port: 587
    protocol: smtp
    properties:
      "mail.transport.protocol": smtp
      "mail.smtp.auth": true
      "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": true

pom.xml package:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>

expected the message to be sent by email, but instead the above error occurred

The problem was solved by replacing the Internet provider (initially it did not work, because I connected to the Wi-Fi of another network with the patch cord of the current network inserted (I don’t know if it was a problem with Windows or the network card itself, that it could not switch the signal, but after switching ) to another network and completely disconnecting from the previous smtp immediately got up and working)).

application.yml
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: myemail@gmail.com
    password: your_app_password_here
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true

Add these on application.yml to enable debug logging for the mail sender
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.mail: DEBUG
    org.apache.commons.mail: DEBUG

Update EmailService Also:
@Service
public class EmailService implements IEmailService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailService.class);
    private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String sender;

    public EmailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    @Override
    public ServiceResponse<String> sendEmail(String recipientEmail, String subject, String message) {
        var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<String>();
        try {
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
            mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(sender);
            mimeMessageHelper.setTo(recipientEmail);
            mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);
            mimeMessageHelper.setText(message);
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
            serviceResponse.data = null;
            serviceResponse.success = true;
            serviceResponse.message = String.format("Security code for %s successfully sent to your email.", subject);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error sending email: {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
            serviceResponse.data = null;
            serviceResponse.success = false;
            serviceResponse.message = ex.getMessage();
        }
        return serviceResponse;
    }
}


hi, thanks, I changed everything, but the errors remained the same.
2024-07-14T14:29:12.578+03:00 ERROR 14272 --- [io-8080-exec-10] h.service.emailService.EmailService      : Error sending email: Mail server connection failed. Failed messages: org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;

What have you changed? What was wrong before?

replaced my files with yours and enabled logging and the errors remain the same
